# How to get Highcharts to work on Blazor Interactive Modes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts, blazor

I want to use Highcharts with Interactive Server as I need some interactive actions like @onclick... but somehow the simple below code only works with Static mode. I think on Interactive Modes, it loads the lib twice causing  the error 16

[image]

```
  @page "/chart"
<h3>Chart</h3>
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts
@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Rendering;
@{
    var chartOptions = new Highcharts
            {
                Chart = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Chart
                {
                    Polar = true,
                    Type = ChartType.Area,
                    MarginTop = 80,
                    BackgroundColor = "#f3f4f6"
                },
                Title = new Title
                {
                    Text = "Highcharts Polar Chart"
                },
                Pane = new Pane
                {
                    StartAngle = 0,
                    EndAngle = 360
                },
                XAxis = new List<XAxis>
                     {
                new XAxis
                {
                    // TickInterval = 45,
                    // Min = 0,
                    // Max = 360,
                    Categories = new List <string> {"Tấn công","Kỹ thuật","Chiến thuật","Phòng thủ","Sáng tạo"},
               Labels = new XAxisLabels
                    {
                        Formatter = "formatXAxisLabels"
                    }
                }
                                     },
                YAxis = new List<YAxis>
                     {
                new YAxis
                {

                    Max=100,
                    GridLineInterpolation=YAxisGridLineInterpolation.Polygon
                }
                                     },

                Series = new List<Series>
                     {

                new AreaSeries
                {
                    Name = "Area",
                    Data = new List<AreaSeriesData> {
                         new AreaSeriesData { Y = 77 },
                        new AreaSeriesData { Y = 67 },
                        new AreaSeriesData { Y = 66 },
                        new AreaSeriesData { Y = 36 },
                        new AreaSeriesData { Y = 66 }
                    }
                }
                                     }
            };



    chartOptions.ID = "chart";
    var renderer = new HighchartsRenderer(chartOptions);

    <span>@((MarkupString)renderer.RenderHtml())</span>
}
<script type="text/javascript">

    function formatXAxisLabels() {
        return this.value + '°';
    }

</script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: You tried to place the highcharts.js load one level up and not in the file that needs to be loaded multiple times?